# How to Dynamically Cast a Template Class

Tags: c++, template-classes, typecasting-operator

I'm trying to write an API around the following class template:

```
template <class A, class B>
class MyClass {
    public:
        A foo;
        B bar;
        MyClass();
        MyClass(A in1, B in2) {
            foo = in1; bar = in2;
        }
        void operator = (MyClass<A, B> in) {
            foo = in.foo; bar = in.bar;
        }
};
```

As a part of this API, I would like implementers to be able to dynamically cast between different types of `MyClass`. In order to accomplish this, I have written the following function:

```
template<class A, class B, class C, class D>
MyClass<C, D> operator MyClass<C, D> (MyClass<A, B> in) {
    MyClass<C, D> out((C)in.foo, (D)in.bar);
    return out;
}
```

This code compiled without errors.

**My Question:**
Assuming that both `C operator C (A)` and `D operator D (B)` are defined for any given implementation of the above function, will this crazy looking function be sufficient to allow implementers to dynamically cast between types of `MyClass`, (via `(MyClass<C, D>)MyClass<A, B>`) or have I completely lost it?

**Example Implementation:**

```
/*
  * --- INCLUDE ABOVE CLASS DEFINITION HERE ---
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    MyClass<int, char> foo(42, 'q');
    MyClass<double, std::string> bar;

    bar = (MyClass<double, std::string>) foo;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal compilable test program? The question is cool.

Comment: Please use the term "dynamically cast" for the operation performed by `dynamic_cast`, to avoid confusion. There is nothing dynamic in what you have shown. Your crazy-looking function doesn't look valid. Type conversion is specified by either `Class::operator TYPE()` nonstatic member function (no arguments, no explicit return type -- conversion from Class to TYPE) or by a single-argument constructor Class::Class(TYPE) (conversion from TYPE to Class).

Comment: @n.m. Apologies, I hadn't realized that typecasting operators weren't considered "dynamic". Perhaps I should review typecasting terminology.

Comment: @n.m. I don't think I fully understand. Could you potentially provide a working alternative?

Comment: E.g http://ideone.com/hIYsui

Comment: @n.m. Interesting, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Answer: YES.

But you must provide ALL VARIANTS OF C operator C (A) and D operator D (B), and you need a copy constructor like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    A foo;
    B bar;
    MyClass(MyClass &cpy)// copy constructor
   {
       foo = cpy.foo;
       bar = cpy.bar;
   }
   MyClass(A in1, B in2)
   {
       foo = in1; bar = in2;
   }
};
```

Copy constructor is required in order to work:

```
    return out;
```

in MyClass(A in1, B in2) method

Comment: Just to clarify: by "all variants...", you mean that to convert from `MyClass<int, char>` to `MyClass<double, string>`, both `double operator double (int)` and `string operator string (char)` must be defined, correct?